# pandas dataframe duplicate values count not properly working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, duplicates

value count is : df['ID'].value_counts().values
-----> array([4,3,3,1], dtype=int64)

**input**:

```
ID emp
a  1
a  1
b  1
a  1
b  1
c  1
c  1
a  1
b  1
c  1
d  1
```

when I jumble the ID column

```py
df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['ID']), 'emp']= df['ID'].value_counts().values
```

**output**:

```
ID emp 
a  4
c  3
d  3
c  1
b  1
a  1
c  1
a  1
b  1
b  1
a  1
```

**expected result**:

```
ID emp 
a  4
c  3
d  1
c  1
b  3
a  1
c  1
a  1
b  1
b  1
a  1
```

**problem** :the count is not checking the ID before assigning it the emp.

Comment: I tried running the code snippet for the given data, output is same as you expected, do you have `ID` column as index? You can join the [yesterday's chat here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233563/discussion-between-dontaccept-and-anubhav-negi)

Comment: i have the ID jumbled :
ID emp
a  4
c  1
d  3
c  1
b  1
a  3
c  1
a  1
b  1
b  1
a  1

Comment: IDK if this has already been asked but `pandas` version?

Comment: >pandas) (1.15.0)

i have updated the question for better understanding

Comment: the ID cant be mapped correctly if I change the ID column sequence.
So is there a way to map the count to the same emp value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is problem ouput of `df['ID'].value_counts()` is `Series` with counted values in different number of values like original data, for new column filled by couter value use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['ID']), 'emp'] = df['ID'].map(df['ID'].value_counts())
```

Or [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `size`:

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['ID']), 'emp'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size')
```

---

Output Series with 4 values cannot assign back, because different index in `df1.index` and `df['ID'].value_counts().index`

```
print (df['ID'].value_counts())
a    4
b    3
c    3
d    1
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

If convert to numpy array only first 4 values are assigned, because in this DataFrame are 4 groups `a,b,c,d`, so `df.duplicated(subset=['ID'])` returned 4 times `True`s, but in order `4,3,3,1` what reason of wrong output:

```
print (df['ID'].value_counts().values)
[4 3 3 1]
```

What need - new column (`Series`) with same `df.index`:

```
print (df['ID'].map(df['ID'].value_counts()))
0     4
1     4
2     3
3     4
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     4
8     3
9     3
10    1
Name: ID, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size'))
0     4
1     4
2     3
3     4
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     4
8     3
9     3
10    1
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for such elaborated explanation, it helped me learn a lot.
And this is working too.
Thanks  a lot

Comment: @AnubhavNegi - Also another answer is accepted, please never use `df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['ID']), 'emp']= df['ID'].value_counts().values`, because wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This alone is giving `df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['ID']), 'emp']= df['ID'].value_counts().values` desired output for your given sample dataframe

but you can try:

```
cond=~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['ID'])

df.loc[cond,'emp']=df.loc[cond,'ID'].map(df['ID'].value_counts())
```

Comment: `df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['ID']), 'emp']= df['ID'].value_counts().values` - no, it is wrong, workign only in this data.

Comment: @AnubhavNegi - Explained in another answer what is wrong

Comment: @jezrael hello sir you are right that it workign only in this data but sir OP want to change the value where `cond` satisfies...pls sir have a look on expected output of OP

Comment: @AnuragDabas - change data `a` to `c` and `df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['ID']), 'emp']= df['ID'].value_counts().values` failed

Comment: @AnubhavNegi see your expected output